# Configuring Seam for Glassfish

Tags: glassfish, seam, glassfish-3, glassfish-embedded

I am still migrating to Glassfish instead of Jetty for our application servers and am running into some problems.  The application starts up fine, the database tables are created by hibernate and data is imported by my database importer, so Seam is alive, running and well.  It appears that Seam is not properly bound to any JSF lifecycle as I'm getting no active application scope:

```
INFO: Initializing filter: com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.security.authenticationFailureEventFilter
Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts flushAndDestroyContexts
SEVERE: could not discover transaction status
Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve log
WARNING: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: PWC1406: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No active application scope
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Init.instance(Init.java:115)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Contexts.flushAndDestroyContexts(Contexts.java:347)
    at org.jboss.seam.contexts.Lifecycle.endRequest(Lifecycle.java:164)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:89)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:73)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:277)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:188)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:641)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:97)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.invoke(PESessionLockingStandardPipeline.java:85)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:185)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:332)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions handle
SEVERE: handled and logged exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.walterjwhite.util.persistence.QueryUtil.setParameter(QueryUtil.java:71)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.web.file.FileAliasFilter.filterHttpServletRequest(FileAliasFilter.java:57)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:30)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:36)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.web.content.WelcomeFilter.process(WelcomeFilter.java:56)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractSinglePassPreFilter.singlePass(AbstractSinglePassPreFilter.java:28)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractSinglePassFilter.filterHttpServletRequest(AbstractSinglePassFilter.java:27)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:30)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher log
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/WalterJWhite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-Development] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.jboss.seam.InstantiationException: Could not instantiate Seam component: com.walterjwhite.listener.exception.exceptionListener
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2156)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:2021)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.getInstance(Component.java:1983)
    at org.jboss.seam.core.Events.raiseEvent(Events.java:77)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions.handle(Exceptions.java:103)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:114)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:497)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:314)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.web.content.WelcomeFilter.process(WelcomeFilter.java:56)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractSinglePassPreFilter.singlePass(AbstractSinglePassPreFilter.java:28)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractSinglePassFilter.filterHttpServletRequest(AbstractSinglePassFilter.java:27)
    at com.walterjwhite.servlet.filter.base.AbstractHttpServletFilter.doFilter(AbstractHttpServletFilter.java:30)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RewriteFilter.doFilter(RewriteFilter.java:63)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Lookup failed for 'java:comp/env/localhost/ExceptionListener/local' in SerialContext  [Root exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/localhost/ExceptionListener/local]
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:442)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiateSessionBean(Component.java:1400)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.instantiate(Component.java:1364)
    at org.jboss.seam.Component.newInstance(Component.java:2134)
    ... 66 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: No object bound to name java:comp/env/localhost/ExceptionListener/local
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.lookup(GlassfishNamingManagerImpl.java:657)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.JavaURLContext.lookup(JavaURLContext.java:148)
    at com.sun.enterprise.naming.impl.SerialContext.lookup(SerialContext.java:428)
    ... 71 more

Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher log
WARNING: ApplicationDispatcher[/WalterJWhite-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-Development] PWC1231: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:522)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:170)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter$1.sendRedirect(RedirectFilter.java:72)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.MockExternalContext.redirect(MockExternalContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:220)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.RedirectHandler.handle(RedirectHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions.handle(Exceptions.java:76)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:114)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Apr 26, 2010 7:31:28 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve log
WARNING: org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@1bb5d98: Exception Processing ErrorPage[exceptionType=java.lang.Throwable, location=/content/error/500.xhtml]
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:126)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:135)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:102)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:88)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:76)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:53)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:57)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:69)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:330)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:309)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:522)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:170)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter$1.sendRedirect(RedirectFilter.java:72)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.MockExternalContext.redirect(MockExternalContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:220)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.RedirectHandler.handle(RedirectHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions.handle(Exceptions.java:76)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:114)
    ... 35 more
----- Root Cause -----
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.ResponseFacade.sendRedirect(ResponseFacade.java:522)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponseWrapper.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseWrapper.java:170)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter$1.sendRedirect(RedirectFilter.java:72)
    at org.jboss.seam.mock.MockExternalContext.redirect(MockExternalContext.java:528)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:220)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.FacesManager.redirect(FacesManager.java:185)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:55)
    at org.jboss.seam.faces.Navigator.redirect(Navigator.java:42)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.RedirectHandler.handle(RedirectHandler.java:51)
    at org.jboss.seam.exception.Exceptions.handle(Exceptions.java:76)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.endWebRequestAfterException(ExceptionFilter.java:114)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:70)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.HotDeployFilter.doFilter(HotDeployFilter.java:53)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:215)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:800)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:664)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:499)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:468)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:364)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:475)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:669)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:334)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:233)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:165)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:791)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:693)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:954)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:170)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.exec
```

Comment: @Walter White Hi Walter, i am curious: Any trouble by using Jetty or just a requirement to replace it by Glassfish ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Seam 3 (my understanding is that Seam 3 gets deployed on top of Weld to extend it)? If not, according to [this thread](http://forums.java.net/jive/message.jspa?messageID=366814):

> The current versions of Seam are not compatible with Glassfish V3, Seam 3 is under development and will be. The core of Seam is now called JCDI (or Webbeans) and should be a part of Glassfish V3, but all the extra (i.e. identity, mail, pdf, etc) will be a part of Seam 3.
>
> You can still use Seam with Glassfish, but you've got to stick with V2.

Just in case, the documentation for Seam on GlassFish v2 is [here](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/2.1.0.SP1/reference/en-US/html/glassfish.html).

Comment: Ah, ok.  Boo hoo.  I thought I heard Dan Allen say it is the same for v2 and v3.

Comment: @Walter The thread mentioned as reference is a bit old, maybe try to get a second confirmation. Anyway, I think that the inclusion of Weld in GlassFish v3 makes things different than with GlassFish v2.

Comment: I'm not using Weld - I guess I will wait for Seam 3 to be released and then perform another infrastructure upgrade.  I am migrating to JSF2 and JPA2 as well, so it will take a little while to get all of these things playing together nicely.